# How to use custom authorize attribute in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I have a custom authorize attribute like this. That works in a controller. I have my own permission table and this table have many-to-many relationship with identity roles table. I can check in controller so that if specified permission is assigned to any roles that authenticates user like this.

> ```
>  [Permission("test")]
>  public IActionResult Index()
>         {
>             return View();
>         }
> ```

also I want do that on view side.

I was tried many methods like this but all methods are based on policy authorization.

```
@if (await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, Model, "test"))
                    {
                    <a href="calendar.html" class="waves-effect">
                        <i class="ti-calendar"></i><span> Calendar</span>
                    </a>
                     ...
                     ...
                    }
```

Here is My Custom authorize attribute codes

```
public class PermissionAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public PermissionAttribute(params string[] permission) : base(typeof(PermissionRequirementFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { permission };

    }
}

public class PermissionRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    readonly string[] _permission;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<ExternalLoginModel> _logger;

    public PermissionRequirementFilter(ApplicationDbContext db, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ILogger<ExternalLoginModel> logger, params string[] permission)
    {
        _db = db;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _permission = permission;
    }


    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {

        if (!IsUserAuthenticated(context))
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }


        // Get all the roles the user belongs to and check if any of the roles has the permission required
        // for the authorization to succeed.
        var id = _userManager.GetUserId(context.HttpContext.User);
        var user = _db.Users.Include(e => e.UserRoles)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Role)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Permissions)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Permission)
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var userRole = user.UserRoles.Select(c => c.Role).ToList();
            var permissions = userRole.SelectMany(c => c.Permissions.Select(e => e.Permission.Label)).ToList();
            if (permissions.Any(c => _permission.Contains(c)))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("succedd.");
                //context.Result = new AcResult();
                return;
            }
        }
        _db.Dispose();

        context.Result = new ForbidResult();
    }
```

Comment: If you need to be authorized to return the view, why would you need to also authorize in the view itself?

Comment: @omarhimadi i dont need authorize in the view.i just to want hide or show some html content on view which user passed to my own authorize attribute

Comment: You're side stepping the built in authorization framework, when all this is already built in and ready to go. Use the tools the framework provides. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x